# How do I create a skill that's smart enough to stay on the skill and not just execute itself once without repeating the invocation name?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I've notice that almost all the skills can't repeat themselves and you have to say the invocation phrase every time you need to use a functionality, so my question is: how do I stop this from happening?

Creating an intent that allows the skill to repeat itself but Its' not working

```
class GetWeatherIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        
        return is_intent_name("GetWeatherIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
    
        city = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots['city'].value

    
        current_weather = cons_clima(city)

       
        speak_output = f"The weather in {city} is {current_weather}."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask("Would you like to know the weather of another city?")
                .response
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible,however, you could launch a skill via a Routine. Alexa routines are an easy way for Alexa to perform a series of actions at the same time, in a certain order. A routine can be triggered from a custom utterance or something else, like an alarm going off. Please check the following blog post for further details:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2019/10/tell-your-customers-they-can-now-invoke-your-skill-from-routines

Also, I would suggest to post it as a feature request on the UserVoice portal for Alexa over here:
https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote